# Unable to use Glimpse. Ambiguity in IApplicationBuilder package

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-1.0, glimpse

I am creating and angular 2 app using asp.net core. I have selected the latest 4.6.1 DotNetFramwork version while creating the project.I have also added the Glimpse package version "2.0.0-beta1". I am having trouble in the startup.cs file as getting conflict with the version of IApplicationBuilder interface

I am getting ambiguity error message for IApplicationBuilder in Configure method of the startup.cs file.
When I select **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder** package , I get a compilation  error saying IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseIISPlatformHandler and UseGlimpse.

If i select the **Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApplicationBuilder** then it complains saying that IApplicationBuilder does not contain definition for UseBrowserLink, UseDeveloperExceptionPage ,UseExceptionHandler and UseIISPlatformHandler.

I am stuck and not sure how to resolve this. Need to use Glimpse in my project.

Could somebody help ?

Below is the copy of my project.json and startup.cs file

**project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
using Glimpse;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace AspNetCoreAngular2Demo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);


        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGlimpse();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder app,
                              IHostingEnvironment env,
                              ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options =>
                                      options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseGlimpse();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default",
                                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback",
                                "{*anything}",
                                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                routes.MapWebApiRoute("defaultApi",
                                      "api/{controller}/{id?}");
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: Had the same problem and followed these instructions and it worked: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype/issues/123#issuecomment-276980579

Answer (score 0):

Glimpse 2 Beta 1 supports .NET Core RC1.

Try using Glimpse 2 Beta 2 from the NuGet feed at https://www.myget.org/gallery/glimpseprototype for .NET Core RTM Support

Comment: I tried adding the entry  "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta2" in the project.json as well added the url https://www.myget.org/gallery/glimpseprototype to the settings Package Source in NugetManager of my Visual Studio 2015 editor. It doesnt download the library and install it. Any clues